# Can't create a 2d array

Tags: c++, vector

I've tried to create a 2d array by the way I found in this guide http://www.cplusplus.com/forum/general/107678/.

But I got this error:

```
Error   1   
error C2664: 'void std::vector<std::vector<Square *,std::allocator<_Ty>>,std::allocator<std::vector<_Ty,std::allocator<_Ty>>>>::push_back(const std::vector<_Ty,std::allocator<_Ty>> &)' : 
cannot convert argument 1 from 'cocos2d::Vector<Square *> *' to 'std::vector<Square *,std::allocator<_Ty>> &&'  f:\hoctap\technology\cocos2d-x\cocos2d-x-3.2\tools\cocos2d-console\bin\lightpuzzel\classes\sprites\table.cpp    63  1   LightPuzzel
```

Here is my code:

```
vector<vector<Square*>> gameTable;

for (int i = 0; i < width; i++){
    auto squares= new Vector<Square*>;
    gameTable.push_back(squares);

    for (int j = 0; j < height; j++){
        auto *_square = new Square();
        gameTable[i].push_back(_square);
    }
}
```

How can I fix this error?

Comment: C++ is case-sensitive: `vector` and `Vector` are different things.  And don't use `new` without a reason.  (Preferably, don't use it at all.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are couple of errors in your code:

1. You are using `vector` instead of `Vector` in the line

   ```
    auto squares= new Vector<Square*>;
   ```
2. You are adding a pointer instead of an object in

   ```
    gameTable.push_back(squares);
   ```

You can replace the lines:

```
 auto squares= new Vector<Square*>;
 gameTable.push_back(squares);
```

with a single line:

```
 gameTable.push_back(vector<Square*>());
```

to take care of both errors.

Comment: Thank you so much. Can you explain more about the differences between adding a pointer and adding an object? I see both ways are ok when I debug.

Comment: @user3601015, you are welcome. If your `vector` is a `vector` of objects, you will not be able to add pointers to that `vector`. The compiler will not let you do that. There's a huge difference between a `vector` of pointers vs a `vector` objects. Too much difference to explain in a comment.

Answer (score 0):

To create a 2d array, you can leverage the [fill constructor](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/vector/vector/vector/).

```
vector<vector<Square*> > gameTable (rowSize, vector<Square*>(columnSize, NULL));
```

Then you can use nested loops to populate the 2d array.

```
for (int i=0; i<rowSize; i++) {
    for (int j=0; j<columnSize; j++) {
        gameTable[i][j] = xxx;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You're `push_back()`'ing a `std::vector<>`, not a `cocos2d::Vector`. The element type of `gameTable` is `std::vector<Square*>`, which is not compatible with the type you're passing in. Change the type signature to:

```c++
std::vector<Vector<Square*>> gameTable;
```

You should also consider using `std::unique_ptr`, and `emplace_back()`'ing those elements:

```c++
std::vector<Vector<std::unique_ptr<Square>>> gameTable;

for (int i = 0; i < width; i++)
{
    gameTable.emplace_back();

    for (int j = 0; j < height; j++)
    {
        gameTable.at(i).push_back(new Square);
    }
}
```

Comment: I don't think you can use a `vector(N, Elem)` constructor involving `std::unique_ptr`.